# Single Page App: Force Users to Log Out or Refresh

Tags: angularjs, deployment, single-page-application

I have created a single page app using AngularJS and ASP.NET MVC 3.  When deploying a new version of the application, it's possible for users to be already logged in as the application is being updated.  If these users don't either refresh their browser or log out and back in again to get the new JavaScript files, they will encounter lots of errors and could potentially create invalid data.

**Question:** in a single page app, is there an elegant way to either prompt users to either refresh their browser or log out and back in again?

I suppose this would be possible through Web Sockets / SignalR, but are there other options?

Answer (score 3):

One generic way I could see is to have your angular app send a client-version # with any http request, and your .NET side watch for that number and when it's out of date ( a newer version has been deployed ) send an error response which you would capture in your angular app. You could then just trigger a refresh or prompt the user to refresh and get the latest version.